# RK4 gives nan for finite element galerkin method with 8+ basis

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, galerkin-methods

Exact Solution = $e^t \sin(\pi(x)) $

$f(x,t) = e^t(1-\beta \pi^2)\sin(\pi(x))$

$H = 1/N$

$ \phi_0 = (H - x)/H \hspace{5mm} in \hspace{5mm} [0, H] \hspace{5mm} else \hspace{5mm} 0 $

$ \phi_N = (x - (N-1)H )/H \hspace{5mm} in \hspace{5mm} [(N-1)H, NH] \hspace{5mm} else \hspace{5mm} 0 $

$ \phi_k = (x -(k - 1)H )/H \hspace{5mm} in \hspace{5mm} [kH, (k+1)H],\hspace{5mm}
((k + 1)H - x )/H \hspace{5mm} in \hspace{5mm} [kH, (k+1)H]
\hspace{5mm} else \hspace{5mm} 0 $

I am trying to solve the equation $ u_t + \beta u_{xx} = f(x,t)$. I have used 
$ u = \sum_{0}^{N}  a_i(t) \phi_i(x) $ as the approximate solution where $\phi_i$
is defined by the triangular hat functions in [0, 1]. I 'm using finite element analysis and using the sense of weak derivatives I have calculated the various stiffness matrices that would be required. I have used hat functions as the test functions too.

After a bit of solving I let 2 tridiagonal matrices and one other with 4 entries. Now I have to solve the system $$ \alpha^{'}_{(n \times 1)}= A^{-1}_{(n \times n)}({D_{(n \times n)}.y_{(n \times 1)} + e^t F_{(n \times 1)}})$$ where $'$ denotes derivatives and subscripts the dimensions of the matrices and $A$, $D$, $F$ are matrices.

I had been trying to solve this system by

- (1) RK4 (self implemented),
- (2) ODE45 (scipy's RK45 and LSODA),
- (3) Backward Euler (self implemented).

For (1) the solution blows up for n=8 basis or elements and further. For (2) LSODA I get the error initially decreasing but increasing after 100 or so basis and overall the $\log (error)$ vs. $\log(H)$ plot is increasing(unexpected). For RK45 I get nan  values both on my solver and scipy's too. For (3) I get decreasing error plot for $\log(error)$ vs $\log(H)$.

Main problem is why the Runge-Kutta method. It is supposed to be the best. I was taking time step as $H^2$ in Runge-Kutta. Distance step is H as N + 1 points line on the x -axis with height of triangle 1 .

Please help me out. I can share the code and whatever's required to elaborate further.

Comment: Could you give also a value or range for $β$ and what time interval your tried to integrate over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some clarifications reached in the comments, esp. establishing that $β=-1$ is negative and including the actual code, that give a different weight to the points raised in the previous answer.

## Construction of the test case

This experiment in the accuracy of the method of lines is based on the heat equation operator $L[u]=u_t-u_{xx}$ with boundary condition operator $R[u]=(u(0),u(1))$.

#### Method of Manufactured Solutions (MMS)

In this method one constructs a test problem as $L[u]=f=L[p]$, $R[u]=R[p]$, $u|_{t=0}=p|_{t=0}$, where $p$ is some smooth function that serves as the known exact solution. Here

1. $p(x,t)=e^t\sin(\pi x)$ giving homogeneous boundary conditions and
2. $p(x,t)=e^t\sin(x)$ giving an inhomogeneous condition at the $x=1$ boundary

By using second order accurate approximation of the space derivatives, the expected error is $O(\Delta t^p+\Delta x^2)$ where $p$ is the order of some fixed-step ODE solver.

The space discretization error can be removed by applying the MMS approach to the discretization $L_h$ of the differential operator, with $\Delta x=h$. Then in $L_h[u_h]=f_h=L_h[p_h]$, $R[u_h]=R[p_h]$ etc. the error of $u_h$ against $p_h$ is only depending on the time. $p_h$ is some preliminary space discretization of $p$, for instance it could be the projection on the piecewise linear functions.

#### Finite element method

The weak solution of the problem satisfies
$$ \partial_t\int_0^1 uw\,dx+\int_0^1u_xw_x\,dx=\int_0^1fw $$
for all differentiable functions $w$ with $w(x=0)=w(x=1)=0$. The finite element solution has $u$ and $w$ in the space of piecewise linear functions in $x$ direction, over the uniform grid of step size $\Delta x=h=\frac1n$, $x_k=kh$.

Set $u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^N u_k(t)\phi_k(x)$, $\phi_k(x)=\max(0, 1-|x/h-k|)$ the hat functions. This results in the well-known coefficient sequences $\frac16[1,4,1]$ and $\frac1{h^2}[-1,2,-1]$ for the scalar products of the $\phi_k$ and the $\partial_x\phi_k$. For $k=1,...,N-1$ this thus results in equations
$$
\frac{u_{k+1}'(t)+4u_k'(t)+u_{k-1}'(t)}6 + \frac{-u_{k+1}(t)+2u_k(t)-u_{k-1}(t)}{h^2}=\frac1h\int_0^1f(x,t)\phi_k(x)\,dx=F_k(t). \tag{FEM}
$$
The integral on the right evaluates for $p(x,t)=e^t\sin(wx)\implies f(x,t)=e^t(1+w^2)\sin(wx)$ to
$$
F_k(t)=e^t(1+w^2)\left(\frac{\sin(wh/2)}{wh/2}\right)^2\sin(wx_k).
$$
Also note that $a\sin(X+H)+b\sin(X)+a\sin(X-H)=(b+2a\cos(H))\sin(X)$.

## Homogeneous case

The continuous problem, the exact solution, the discretization and all difference and differential operators are symmetric so that the solution will always be a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$ up to floating point errors that are continuously dampened by the properties of the heat equation. The exact solution of the discretized equation will thus have the form $u_k(t)=a(t)\sin(\pi x_k)$, $a(0)=1$, and satisfy the differential equation
$$
\frac{(4+2\cos(\pi h))}6a'(t)\sin(\pi x_k)
+\frac{2(1-\cos(\pi h))}{h^2}a(t)\sin(\pi x_k)
=e^t(1+\pi^2)\left(\frac{\sin(\pi h/2)}{\pi h/2}\right)^2\sin(\pi x_k)
\\\iff\\
a'(t) + \pi^2 c(h)a(t) = c(h)(1+\pi^2) e^t,~~
c(h)=\frac{\left(\frac{\sin(\pi h/2)}{\pi h/2}\right)^2}{\frac{(4+2\cos(\pi h))}6}=1+O(h^2)
$$
The numerical solver for the system will effectively solve this scalar equation with solution
$$
a(t)=\frac{1+\pi^2}{1+c(h)\pi^2} (e^t-e^{-c(h)\pi^2 t})+e^{-c(h)\pi^2 t}
$$
The error against the prescribed function $e^t$ is proportional to $c(h)-1=O(h^2)$ which is also observed in the numerical experiments.

## Inhomogeneous case

In the equation (FEM) for the index $k=n-1$ the outer node $u_n(t)$ is not zero and also not constant, so it has a contribution to both the time derivative term and to the second order space difference term. As $u_n(t)$ is not a variable in the state vector for the method-of-lines ODE system, these components have to be added to the forcing term on the right side. In code this could look like

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1); #0 - 1
H = x[1]-x[0];
S = np.sin(x[1:-1]);
p = lambda t:math.exp(t) * self.alpha
b_c_start = lambda t : 0
b_c_end = lambda t :math.exp(t)*math.sin(1)
                    
A = sp.diags([1/6, 2/3, 1/6], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(N-1, N-1));
Ainv = sp.linalg.splu;
D = sp.diags([-1, 2, -1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(N-1, N-1));
eN = np.zeros(N-1); eN[N]=1; 
DN=-eN;
AN = eN/6;
F = (math.sin(H/2)/(H/2))**2 * (1+1) * S #incomplete without exp(t)

def MoLfunc (self, t,  y):
    # vectorized = False, default
    yN = b_c_end(t)
    Dy = H**-2*(D.dot(y) + DN*yN);
    return Ainv.solve(np.exp(t)*F - AN*yN - Dy);
```

Also note that the error has to be computed as of the continuous function over $[0,1]$. This means that the Euclidean norm of the difference of the solution vector to the prescriped function values has to be scaled by $\sqrt{h}$ to approximate the $L^2$ norm.

## Conclusion

With all these corrections the integration proceeds without problem and the estimated exponent of $h$ in the error is close to 2, $1.996$ in the homogeneous case and $1.99986$ in the inhomogeneous case. The differences are due to details in the computations , the ODE solver used and the error tolerances passed to it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98861/discussion-on-answer-by-lutzl-rk4-gives-nan-for-finite-element-galerkin-method-w).